# disable form fields based on user preference

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have an angular material form with an mat-input and a mat-dropdown. If user populates the input I want the dropdown to be disabled, or if user populates dropdown i would like the input field to be disabled.I know there is a [disabled] attribute in ngmodeloption but i am not using it correctly. Can any let me know where i am going wrong, here is code:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="info.dao">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width ">
        <mat-label>Select Person</mat-label>
        <mat-select  [ngModelOptions]=
            [(ngModel)]="info.selectionPerson">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let info of info.comp" [value]="comp.id">
                {{comp.location}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [disabled] attribute and pass the expression like:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="info.dao" [disabled]="info.selectionPerson">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="example-full-width ">
    <mat-label>Select Person</mat-label>
    <mat-select [disabled]="info.dao"
        [(ngModel)]="info.selectionPerson">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let info of info.comp" [value]="comp.id">
            {{comp.location}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

you don't need ngModelOptions to achieve this.

Comment: Usman thanks for ure response, this disabled dropdown and kept input enabled. I would like it to disable other form field if user populates one.  so if i populated dropdown and  it will disable input and vice versa. can you add an correction to fit this use case?